# Behaviour of the derivative given a local maximum that is not a global maximum

Tags: calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth. Suppose that $f'(0) = 0$ and $f''(0) < 0$. If $f(1) > f(0)$, must there exist a point $x \in (0, 1)$ such that $f'(x) = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the limit defining $f''(0)$, we know that $f'(x)<0$ for all sufficiently small positive $x$ (i.e., for some $x\in (0,1)$). From the MVT, we know that $f'(x)>0$ for some $x\in(0,1)$. From IVT applied to $f'$, we find that $f'(0)=0$ for some $x\in(0,1)$.

---

*Remark:* So we do not need $f$ to be very smooth. If we replace the IVT at the end with the Darboux property of derivatives, the smoothness of $f$ can be reduced to: $f$ is continuos on $[0,1]$, differentiable on $[0,1)$, and $f''(0)$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

A solution by logical thinking!!

Since $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)<0$, there exists a local maxima at $x=0$. Also , since $f(1)>f(0)$, we can conclude that the graph of the function $f$, in the interval $[0,1]$, first decreased and then increased. Assuming the function is continuous and differenciable over the interval $[0,1]$, the graph would must have made a turn back (the point from which decreasing changes to increasing). At this point, the slope must be zero and thus, there exists a $x\in (0,1)$ such that $f'(x)=0$.